# Knowing the size of bitmap on sd card before saving it on sdcard

Tags: android, file, bitmap

I have to compress the bitmap after downloading from http server if the image size is going to take 100KB on SD card, If it is upto 100 KB then don't compress.

So, I want to know the size of bitmap on sd card before saving it on sdcard, So that I could compress the bitmap, if necessary.
The size that    image.getRowHeight()*image.getHeight() gives is different than file.length().

Comment: Most image formats are already compressed, doing again a compression is therefore useless in most cases.

Comment: @Henry I have jpg format of images?

Comment: jpg is already compressed. You can try to compress it again with some test images, there is not much to be gained.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [official android document](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html), following technique allows you to read the dimensions and type of the image data prior to construction (and memory allocation) of the bitmap.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
```

To see the file size in bytes, use `File.length()`

Comment: I am to know the size in bytes. Height and width helps to give size at the allocation time.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `Content-Lenght` header field of the response using your http client.

[rfc2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)

> The Content-Length entity-header field indicates the size of the
>   entity-body, in decimal number of OCTETs, sent to the recipient or, in
>   the case of the HEAD method, the size of the entity-body that would
>   have been sent had the request been a GET.

Comment: Simply using content-length is fine Or any care should be taken with this?

Comment: Value of the `Content-Lenght` holds the size of the image being downloaded, so it's perfectly fine using it unless there is no `Content-Encoding: gzip, deflate` header. But there shouldn't be for image requests.

Comment: In my case, I dont get any value in "content-length" header.

Comment: Can you post the url to the image?